# How to return data from .this in js

Tags: javascript, promise, return, fetch

So when we give this function getApiData something to fetch, we want it to actually return the fetched data. At the moment it returns "undefined" and we don't understand why.

````
    console.log(name)
    if (`${restVar}` != `GET`) {
        bodyData = JSON.stringify(bodyData);
    }
    fetch(`${url}`, {
        method: `${restVar}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: bodyData
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
            return data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error)
        });
}```

Any help would be much appreciated :)
````

Comment: Duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What do you mean? `console.log('Success:', data);` shows 'undefined'?

Comment: @OnkiHara console.log('Success:', data); doesn't show undefined, but "return data" returns undefined. We want it to return data.

Comment: Then you should check out the link provided by @Samathingamajig. You're accessing probably the return value before the async-call is finished. The `return data` in the then-branch returns into nowhere. You should process the data there.

Comment: It doesn't "return[] into nowhere", it `resolve`s a Promise. If you `return fetch(...);`, you will return that Promise and you can get the value with `await` or `.then`

Comment: @Samathingamajig: Sure, the fetch() returns a promise, that is resolved in the .then-branch. But where does the data from `return data` go?

Comment: @OnkiHara Every `.then` returns a new Promise. See the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: But IMHO you can only access the returned data by adding another resolver, which was not done. So it ended into nowhere.